# Why is Arduino not going through the if/then/elseif as expected when receiving bytes over serial?

Tags: if-statement, arduino, logic, serial-communication

I'm working on a project where the Arduino should do different things based on different characters (`a`, `b`, etc.) being received over Serial. I have gotten it to respond, but I hit a logic error. When I enter `a`, it does as requested and does the soft-reset procedure (grounding the reset pin through a resistor to reset itself remotely). However, when I do `b` (or any other of the 30-some other characters, none of which are identical), it does the `a` command. It should, based on my logic, not do `a`'s code since `incomingByte != 'a'`, but it does `= b`. Why is it running `a` and not anything else? Thanks for any help.

P.S. I am aware there are other methods of doing this, which are likely more 'proper,' but I would like to stick with this if/then/elseif logic if possible.

I have attached some of the code below, there's a lot more so I know there might be a missing `}` there somewhere at the end, but it's there in the code.

```
void loop() {
    char incomingByte;
    //wait for commands
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    bool alarmState = false;
    //variable for storing status of the alarm system for use during unsilence controls, to ensure operator cannot
    //unsilence a non-alarmed system and cause audible signals to activate prematurely

    //use incomingByte as the command byte in ain if/then/elseif
    if (incomingByte = "a") {
    //code to soft-reset
      //output reset confirmation
      tone(buzzer, 600, 500);
      Serial.println("System reset in progress...");
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(powerLED, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(resetPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(troubleLED, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(resetPin, HIGH);  //this is needed to complete the reset

    }
    else if (incomingByte = "b") {
      //code to silence audible signals
      if (alarmState = true) {
      digitalWrite(NAC1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(silenceLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(silence1, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Audible signals silenced");
      }
      else if (alarmState = false) {
        Serial.println("The system is not in alarm and the NAC state could not be modified. If you need to manually override NAC states without system alarm, use the System menu.");
      }
    }
    else if (incomingByte = "c") {
      //code to unsilence audible signals
      if (alarmState = true) {
      digitalWrite(NAC1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(silenceLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(silence1, LOW);
      Serial.println("Audible signals unsilenced");
      }
      else if (alarmState = false) {
        Serial.println("The system is not in alarm and the NAC state could not be modified. If you need to manually override NAC states without system alarm, use the System menu.");
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is not a comparison but an assignment which will always return as true.

```
if (incomingByte = "a") {
```

Comparison in c++ should be done in the following way

```
if (incomingByte == 'a') {
```

This also applies to the other characters and boolean data you are comparing.

Make this change and your code will enter the right if else condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm used to VB.NET, which is being used as a graphical frontend for this alarm system controller, so admittedly I'm still in VB mode ;)

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the correct one, so that if someone else comes to this one, they know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Yep, already did. Site told me to wait a few minutes otherwise it would have been clicked sooner